# Flutter local notification with action buttons and image

Tags: android, ios, flutter, push-notification, dart-pub

I want to push this type of notification with a firebase message. Now the time I am using a normal notification with https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications this package. But I didn't see there is a way to add an Action button. As well as I want to remove this notification after 45second or with another firebase message. as well I'm developing this application for android and ios. If my question is not clear or need more information please free to comment.

[image]

I saw a Similar Question on Stackoverflow.

- [Flutter local notification with action buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60396007/flutter-local-notification-with-action-buttons)
- [Notification with action buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45077920/notification-with-action-buttons)

Answer (score 7):

flutter_local_notification has yet to have support for Notification Action Buttons as mentioned on this [ticket](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/issues/17). You may want to consider using [awesome_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications) plugin in the meantime since it has support for notification buttons.

To show notification with Action Button, simply use

```dart
void _showNotificationWithButton() {
  AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
    content: NotificationContent(
        id: 10,
        channelKey: 'basic_channel',
        title: 'Simple Notification',
        body: 'Simple body'),
    actionButtons: <NotificationActionButton>[
      NotificationActionButton(key: 'yes', label: 'Yes'),
      NotificationActionButton(key: 'no', label: 'No'),
    ],
  );
}
```

You can then add the icon for the Action Button by adding the icon property on NotificationActionButton. The icon should be a String resource of the image mapped in the assets.

To listen for the Action Button press, use an actionStream listener. You can add this on the screen's `initState()`

```dart
AwesomeNotifications().actionStream.listen((receivedNotification) {
  // prints the key of the NotificationActionButton pressed
  debugPrint('Notification key pressed: ${receivedNotification.buttonKeyPressed}');
});
```

Comment: this notification always shows in notificaiton tray , Its not shows on top of screen

Comment: receivedNotification.buttonKeyPressed is not found

Comment: What should I enter in channelKey and id ?

Comment: this will work only when application is in foreground state?

Answer (score 2):

The answer consists of two parts:

1. Creating heads-up notification.
2. Showing action buttons in the notification.

---

### 1 ** Creating heads-up notification

we are gonna use this package [awesome_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications).

This how to initialize it in the `main()` method of your project

```
AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
  // set the icon to null if you want to use the default app icon
  null,
  [
    NotificationChannel(
      channelGroupKey: 'channel_group_key',
      channelKey: 'channel_key',
      channelName: 'channel_name',
      channelDescription: 'channel_description',
      importance: NotificationImportance.Max,
    )
  ],
  debug: true,
);
```

Android initialization only:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
  <application>
    ...
     <activity
       android:name=".MainActivity"
       android:showOnLockScreen="true"
       android:showWhenLocked="true"
       android:turnScreenOn="true">
       ...
     </activity>
   ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

**Note:** On iOS, you need to request for notifications permissions. And on Android 11, you need to request for `fullScreenIntent`. Here's the code (put it in `initState()` or whatever):

```
AwesomeNotifications().isNotificationAllowed().then(
  (isAllowed) {
    //It would be more appropriate if you can show your own dialog
    //to the user before requesting the notifications permissons.
    if (!isAllowed) {
      AwesomeNotifications().requestPermissionToSendNotifications(
        permissions: [
          NotificationPermission.Alert,
          NotificationPermission.Sound,
          NotificationPermission.Badge,
          NotificationPermission.Vibration,
          NotificationPermission.Light,
          NotificationPermission.FullScreenIntent,
        ],
      );
    }
  }
);
```

And how to create the notification, put it whenever you need to fire the notification:

```
AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
  content: NotificationContent(
    id: 10,
    channelKey: 'channel key' //Same as above in initilize,
    title: title,
    body: body,
    wakeUpScreen: true,
    fullScreenIntent: true,
    criticalAlert: true,
    //Other parameters
  ),
);
```

---

### 2 ** Showing action buttons in the notification

In the previous code snippet when creating the notification, you can add the action buttons to it like that:

```
AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
  //...
  actionButtons: <NotificationActionButton>[
    NotificationActionButton(key: 'accept', label: 'Accept'),
    NotificationActionButton(key: 'reject', label: 'Reject'),
  ],
);
```

You can add icons, text fields and so many other things. Look [here](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications#notificationactionbutton-actionbuttons-in-push-data---optional) for more.

And to listen for the tapped button, here's the code:

```
AwesomeNotifications().actionStream.listen(
  (ReceivedAction receivedAction) {

  if (receivedAction.buttonKeyPressed == 'accept') {
    //Your code goes here
  } else if (receivedAction.buttonKeyPressed == 'reject') {
    //Your code goes here
  }

  //Here if the user clicks on the notification itself
  //without any button

  },
);
```

---

### The [awesome_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications) package is so extensive, I recommend you to learn about it more from their page.