# Easiest Python framework for implementing Android notifications with buttons

Tags: python, kivy, android-notifications, flet, android-notification-action

I'm looking for a mobile app development Python framework (possibly Kivy or Flet or something similar) that allows me to build an Android app with local push notifications that have buttons. So far I have seen the following:

- [Make dynamic notification in Kivy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kEk8CMlEdw)

  - This example appears to support desktop only
- [Flutter local notifications with buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67791021/flutter-local-notification-with-action-buttons-and-image)

  - This requires installing the awesome_notifications plugin for Flutter. Since I'm looking for a python framework only that leaves me with Flet, but I'm not sure if Flet can wrap Flutter widgets that aren't included in the standard library

I've only seen examples on Kivy for simple notifications (via plyer). I would like the notification to have buttons on it that allow the user to interact with the notification.
Is there a Python framework thats allows me to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I have tried several, and I found [Briefcase and BeeWare suite](https://beeware.org/project/projects/tools/briefcase/) to be the most usable. I'm not sure about the flutter notifications, but Android app development is limited with Python. Toga is the GUI framework, which is widget based, so you can check their docs for notifications. You may have an easier time using Kotlin, C++, JavaScript, Java, etc for Android development, but BeeWare suite is the most inclusive Python framework for Android development I have found.